Custom cache OkHttp
I'd like to cache API request in my app so that user could see something even if they are offline.
I also have a HeaderInterceptor with multiple headers, such as language such as en, es, fr etc... The same endpoint returns different result depending on the header language.
From what I've read in the OkHttp source code, cache only cares about the url, so even if my user changes language and a new request is made a different header, he'll get the cache response instead of a making a new call.
How can I create a custom cache that will take into account header as well ?

Ideally, Cache would be an interface, not a class.  Could you switch OkHttpClient instances based on the same logic that determines your language? You could then have separate caches per language.

I can't separate cache based on language because in this example it's only language. I'm pretty sure I'll have to extends the caching strategy to language and one or more headers

OK. Another possibility is outlined in this issue comment, where you hack the URL that gets used for the cache key. In their case, it is removing a parameter; in your case, you would introduce fake parameters based on your headers.

I'm gonna try that and create a feature request as well

If you get it working, please consider posting an answer with your solution!

You server should be setting a Vary header
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Vary
If you apply your header in an application interceptor, OkHttp should honour the Vary header
